# How to save default data in other fields with a POST request on DJANGO?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

There is a "goods" model with the fields: "name", "quantity", "expense", "balance". on the page of the filling form there is only a "name" and "quantity"". it is necessary that, together with the given "name" and "quantity" in the database, the values ​​in the "expense" and "balance" fields are also saved (in the "expense" by default "0", in the "balance" the same value as in the "quantity")
P.s sorry for my english

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please try writing the code yourself first and then add what you've got to the question so we can help you continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a default value in the model field, e.g.

```py
expense = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

As for setting the balance to the quantity, you would need to get the instance before saving it - so would need to override the save function:

```py
Class MyModel(models.Model):
#...

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.balance = self.quantity
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```